# proving $a^2_{n+1}-a^2_{n}=a_{n+1} \cdot a_{n} $ is a Geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-progressions

How can i prove that: $a^2_{n+1}-a^2_{n}=a_{n+1} \cdot a_{n} $ is a Geometric progression?

I think i can solve Quadratic equation but maybe there is a simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah! Just solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: cool thanks, i just wonder if there are other methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide both sides by $a_n^2$ and define $b=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$; you should find that the resulting equation is particularly simple.  (And in particular, that $b$ is a constant independent of $n$, as the notation suggests.)

(**ETA:** As Jack D'Aurizio notes in a comment, this isn't quite a complete solution - in fact, the original claim is *false* without the restriction that we take $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$, as otherwise one could choose 'alternating' solutions of the quadratic.  With that restriction, this proof goes through smoothly.)

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: a second degree equation has two solutions, say $b$ and $\bar{b}$. What if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=b$ while $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}=\bar{b}$ and, in general, the ratio between two consecutive terms is either $b$ or $\bar{b}$ with no apparent regularity?

Comment: also need to say that $a^2_n$ not zero.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not a minor nitpick at all! In fact, if negative values are allowed then the original question is incorrect for similar reasons. (One could, for instance, alternate or even choose randomly between the two solutions.)

Comment: can you give an example that it could be false? i cant understand that

Comment: @123454 With the restriction that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ (and the constraint that $a_0\neq 0$, since otherwise the solution is trivial) then the fact that the rest of the $a_i$ are nonzero follows from the observation that $a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2\geq 0$ so $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @123454 Suppose one starts with $a_0=1$, then $a_1=\phi$ ($=\frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$), then $a_2=\phi\varphi=-1$ (where $\varphi=-\frac12(\sqrt{5}-1)$), then $a_3=\phi^2\varphi=-\phi$, $a_4=\phi^2\varphi^2=1$, etc.  The ratio between terms isn't constant, but you should find that this series is a valid solution to the original equation.

Comment: oh i see that! thanks alot

Comment: +1 for using the substitution $b = \dfrac {a_{n + 1}}{a_n}$ to turn the original to a more natural quadratic equation. Most often, some will just treat and solve the odd looking original as quadratic without knowing why one can do that. | The part that I don’t quite understand is your example given in the comment. If the roots are $\phi(positive)$ and $\psi(negative)$, there will be TWO sequences. One is {$a_{n+1} = a_n \phi$} and the other is {$a_{n+1} = a_n \psi$} with the latter being alternating. $\phi$ and $\psi$ need not be multiplied together.

Comment: @mick The point is that since $a_{n+1}$ is only dependent on $a_n$, there are actually _infinitely_ many sequences; one can multiply by _either_ $\phi$ or $\varphi$ at each step.  The two you list are the only two that are geometric series, but there are many many others that satisfy the equation (including the one I gave as an example in my comment).